# Include a file passing a parameter

Tags: external-files, include

Is it possible, while including a file, to pass some parameters to that file and get included file rendered differently depending on those parameters? My particular case is, I have two documents, which will have the same title page except for one string - the title of the document itself. So my idea, instead of creating two separate title page `.tex` files would be to make one parameterized one. Here's a rough sketch of the idea:

#### `title_page_template.tex`:

```
% assign parameter, let's call it NAME
% create the top of  the page, logos, etc.
\large NAME
% create the bottom of the page, authors, footer, etc.
```

#### `document1.tex`:

```
% initialization, usepackage, etc.
\include {title_page_template, Document1}
% the rest of the document
```

#### `document2.tex`:

```
% initialization, usepackage, etc.
\include {title_page_template, Document2}
% the rest of the document
```

I would like both documents to have the same title page included except for this one string that is passed as a parameter. Can you do something like that in Latex?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but a more generic approach would be to create your template with the title having the form (in `title_page_template.tex`):

```
\Large \titlename
```

and then call (in `document1.tex`):

```
% initialization, usepackage, etc.
\def\titlename{Document1}%
\include {title_page_template}
% the rest of the document
```

and (in `document2.tex`):

```
% initialization, usepackage, etc.
\def\titlename{Document2}%
\include {title_page_template}
% the rest of the document
```

This leaves some of the structured commands like `\input` untouched, since you might want to use them in a different instance *without* passing parameters.