# parameter passing to \addcontentsline

Tags: include

According to this thread
[Include a file passing a parameter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130348/include-a-file-passing-a-parameter)

it should be as simple as

```
\def\thetitle{longtitle}
\include{text}
```

It actually works pretty well but not for the table of contents.

in the "text" file, I have a line to manually add the title to my table of content and the pages all refer to the last added longtitle

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bf \thetitle}
```

In the main file

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\def\thetitle{title1}
\include{test}

\def\thetitle{title2}
\include{test}
\end{document}
```

The table of contents contains title2 twice and both refers to the same page, the second one.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please complete your code so that it can be compiled to reproduce the problem. Fragments are nowhere near as much use as a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your problem.

Comment: I figured people could add a begin{document} and thus save some space in the presentation.  In providing no solution, I find it hard to call this a "fix" but thank you anyway.

Comment: I don't know what's going on here. But until we have something that replicates the problem, I'm voting to close this...

Comment: @Werner The question should be kept open. The problem is reproducible and is caused by using the same file name in `\include` twice. This is also the difference to the referred question, where there are two main documents including the same file once.

Answer (score 3):

The file `test` is included twice:

```
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\def\thetitle{title1}
\include{test} % first

\def\thetitle{title2}
\include{test} % second
\end{document}
```

The `\addcontentsline` command writes it action to the `.aux` file. In this case it goes into the `.aux` file of the included file, `test.aux`.

By calling `\include{test}` twice, the second `\include` statement will overwrite `test.aux`. Thus at the end, `test.aux` will only contain the data of the second calling of `\include{test}` (with `title2`). When the `.toc` file is written, `test.aux` is read twice and you get the contents entry with `title2` twice.

Therefore the files for `\include` must be unique, The same file must not be used more than once in a `\include` statement. If you want to include a file twice, then you have to resort to `\input`. Or tricks at the operating system layer can be used as linking the file to different names to get unique names for `\include`.